# Importing sklearn module in pyscript

Tags: scikit-learn, pyscript

how to import modules which are in form of
"from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor" in Pyscript?

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question. Note that it you should include code snippets of your coding problem. Otherwise it is difficult to understand what your challenge is exactly.

Answer (score 3):

The way you import modules works as follows:

1. Include the relevant package in the environment

```
<py-env>
- scikit-learn
</py-env>
```

2. Import the module as you would do it in any other python file

```
<py-script>
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
...
</py-script>
```